# How to check Int array(Key) in Dictionary using ContainsKey method?

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

I have a Dictionary collection with integer array as a Key and Image as Value. I need to check whether if same key is already exists or not , before adding `new int[]`.

I have tried below code, but the `Dictionary.ContainsKey(int[])` method will always fails, even the same `key` is already exists.

```
Dictionary<int[], Image> temp = new Dictionary<int[], Image>();
int[] rowcol = new int[]{rowIndex,colIndex};
if (!temp.ContainsKey(rowcol))
{
    animatedImage = style.BackgroundImage;
    temp.Add(rowcol, animatedImage);
}
```

Please suggest me how to check the `int[]` `key` in `Dictionary`?

Thanks

Comment: Use a `Tuple<int, int>`.

Comment: You're passing difference instances of an array which happens to contain the same items, of course they'll not be seen as the same. `new[] { 1 } == new[] { 1 }` also returns false.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
private void sample()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int colIndex = 0;
    Dictionary<int[], Image> temp = new Dictionary<int[], Image>();
    int[] rowcol = new int[] { rowIndex, colIndex };


    if (!(temp.Where(k => k.Key == rowcol).Count() > 0))
    {
        animatedImage = style.BackgroundImage;
        temp.Add(rowcol, animatedImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. That will not work because you also compare references. Changing `k.Key == rowcol` to `k.Key.SequenceEqual(rowcol)` might work but you'll lost the advantages of a dictionary over a list. Btw: you iterate over the all values even if the first value matches your contraint. Using `Any()` instead of `Count()` will stop after the first occurance.